# convert image at command line to console stream

Tags: linux, command-line, conversion, imagemagick

I'm looking for something like ImageMagick's "convert" but that outputs to the console.

The obvious answer is "create a temp file and cat that" but I'd prefer not to have to go to the trouble.

Are there any linux utilities that do this?

Comment: I really doubt there will be one that is simpler than `convert foo.png foo.jp && cat foo.jpg`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066173/using-imagemagick-without-making-files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ImageMagick `convert` if you specify the output filename as `-` then it outputs to stdout.  So something like `convert myimage.jpg -resize 50% - | do-something-with-resized-image`.

To specify that the output type should be different than the input type precede the dash with the type:.  So for example: `convert myimage.jpg png:- | do-something-with-my-png`.

Another alternative would be to look into [netpbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/getting_netpbm.php).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  It seems like convert goes off of the filename - how would I go about specifying the output type?

Comment: precede "-" with "type:".  I added an example to my answer.